# What is the function of this code expression?

Tags: perl

I'm confused with the function of the regular expression:

`/\[\]$/`

I tried out a short perl code to understand it but I'm still confused. The code output is `Else`

```
my $addr2 = {[{'firstname' => 'Nikhil', 'lastname' => 'Hegde'}, {'firstname' => 'Nikhil2', 'lastname' => 'Hegde2'}]};
if($addr2 =~ /\[\]$/) {
    print "If\n";
} 
else {
    print "Else\n";
}
```

I thought that `/\[\]$/` would point to whether the value is an array or not but that doesn't seem to be the case. I then thought that maybe the value has to end with an array considering that there is a `$` in the regular expression. So, I tried substituting:

`my $addr2 = {[{'firstname' => 'Nikhil', 'lastname' => 'Hegde'}, {'firstname' => 'Nikhil2', 'lastname' => 'Hegde2'}],[]};`

but that doesn't work either. The code output remains `Else`.

Can anyone help me in understanding the expression `/\[\]$/`? What regular matching does it do? Thanks!

Comment: That matches literal `[]` (bracket pair), at the end of the string. So it matches for the string `"hello []"`, but not for `"hello"`. Without escaping the brackets are the _character class_.  Also, a basic fact  may be needed: regex works on a string -- which may be in a variable, but you tried it on a _complex data structure_.

Comment: timed out ... to continue --  Your `$addr2` prints as `HASH(...)` -- and that string does not have `[]` at its end.

Comment: @zdim Thanks! That explained a lot

Comment: Add `print("$addr2\n");` and you'll understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A regular expression checks matching of strings. In your case, you tried matching a hash reference. That's why your code went to the `else` block.

Now, the `/\[\]$/`. It matches any *string* that has a literal `[]` at the end of it. For example, the string `my $str = "just an example []"` would match this regex.

Comment: Note that we can match a reference -- `perl -wE '$ra = [1,2]; say $ra if $ra =~ /AR/'`.  It's just that a hashref doesn't have the `[]` at the end :)

Comment: @zdim gotta say I never thought of that option! You can never know when something so weird might come in handy

Comment: Maybe data dumper output of `$addr2` would clarify what's going on?

Comment: @yonyon100: I can't imagine that being useful. You can already compare two references for equality with `==`, and the better way top detect an *array* reference would be `say $ra if ref $ra eq 'ARRAY'`

Comment: @Sobrique, Not at all. The OP is matching against the stringification of `$addr2`, so `print("$addr2\n");` is what would clarify what's going on.